# migrating to material design with angular5

Tags: material-design, angular5

I am developing an angular4 app with bootstrap.
I just moved to angular5 and I wonder if is not the case to use material design for components instead of prime-ng ng-bootrap kendo-ui etc...
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In console:

```
ng new pjt
cd pjt

npm install @angular/material @angular/cdk --save
npm install @angular/animations --save
```

Create app/modules/material.module.ts file and include:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
imports: [MatButtonModule],
exports: [MatButtonModule],
})

export class MaterialModule { }
```

Note each element Mat...Module you want to use needs to be added in the above file comma separated to the import, imports and exports lines.

update app/app.modules.ts to include

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from './modules/material.module';
...
imports: [
...
BrowserAnimationsModule,
MaterialModule
],
```

update styles.scss to include

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

In console

```
npm install hammerjs --save
```

update main.ts to include

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

update index.html to include

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

In console

```
ng serve
```

Then you can start including in your components the material elements, e.g. `<button mat-button>Some Btn<button>` 
... check out [material.angular.io](http://material.angular.io) for elements ...

then check out https://coursetro.com/posts/code/113/How-to-Build-an-Angular-5-Material-App for more details.